# Building issue after migration to Xcode 7: ld: framework not found -L/

Tags: clang, swift2, xcode7

I recently updated my Xcode from 6.4 to 7, and have fixed all my code to be Swift 2 compatible.

I am having an issue: when building my project, the following error arises:

> ld: framework not found -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have tried to alter the library search path in the build settings by adding:

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)
$(inherited)
```

but have not resulted in any progress.

This is the complete error note:

> Ld
>   /Users/UserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Appname\1-eekisechftoomidopihcmbkefaua/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Appname\1.app/Appname\1
>   normal x86_64
>       cd "/Users/UserName/Desktop/Appname1 - iOS app/Appname1 - Swift 2 : xcode 7 - New/Appname1"
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk
>   -L/Users/UserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Appname\1-eekisechftoomidopihcmbkefaua/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/UserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Appname\1-eekisechftoomidopihcmbkefaua/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F. -FFacebookSDKStrings.bundle -FAppname\1 -FAppname\1Tests -FAppname\1UITests -FFacebookSDKStrings.bundle/Resources -FAppname\1/PNChart -FAppname\1/Appname_o.xcdatamodeld -FAppname\1/VoteLogDataBase.xcdatamodeld -FAppname\1/PNChart/PNBarChart -FAppname\1/PNChart/PNLineChart -FAppname\1/Appname_o.xcdatamodeld/Appname_o.xcdatamodel -FAppname\1/VoteLogDataBase.xcdatamodeld/VoteLogDataBase.xcdatamodel -filelist /Users/UserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Appname\1-eekisechftoomidopihcmbkefaua/Build/Intermediates/Appname\1.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Appname\1.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Appname\1.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /Users/UserName/Desktop/Appname\1\ -\ iOS\ app/Appname\1\ -\ Swift\ 2\ :\ xcode\ 7\ -\ New/Appname\1
>   -mios-simulator-version-min=9.0 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -framework -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator
>   -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/UserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Appname\1-eekisechftoomidopihcmbkefaua/Build/Intermediates/Appname\1.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Appname\1.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Appname_o.swiftmodule
>   -framework Accounts -framework AudioToolbox -framework ParseFacebookUtilsV4 -framework ParseFacebookUtils -framework
>   FBSDKShareKit -framework CFNetwork -framework ParseCrashReporting
>   -framework CoreData -framework FBAudienceNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework ParseUI -lsqlite3.0
>   -framework FBSDKMessengerShareKit -lz -framework Bolts -framework FBSDKLoginKit -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore
>   -framework ParseTwitterUtils -framework Security -framework Social -framework SystemConfiguration -framework FBSDKCoreKit -framework Twitter -framework Bolts -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker
>   /Users/UserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Appname\1-eekisechftoomidopihcmbkefaua/Build/Intermediates/Appname\1.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Appname\1.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Appname\1_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/UserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Appname\1-eekisechftoomidopihcmbkefaua/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Appname\1.app/Appname\1
>
> ld: framework not found
>   -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Comment: I believe I had to remove those values from the search path, not add them.  Have you tried without them?

Comment: Yes I did, to no avail. I thought it was an Xcode 7 issue, but I did a clean out of the box project and the build was successful. Can't seem to find out why this is happening to my existing project.

Comment: It almost certainly has to do with your library search path.  Are you sure you're modifying the correct target?  I just looked at the project I converted to Swift 2 and Xcode 7 I saw this issue on and all of my targets have no value for that setting.

Comment: Yeah I am sure, side note: the framework search path was empty, but I had some issues with importing my bridge header and I fixed it by adding $(PROJECT_DIR), not sure if this caused it. But my library search path for all is empty.

Comment: I believe framework search paths would cause an error that started with -F, not -L.  Another simple question: have you tried doing a "Clean Build Folder..." in the Product menu (you have to hold down the Option key)?

Comment: Yup, tried that as well. it is very confusing

Comment: Doesn't hurt to entirely delete the derived data folder from the Projects window either.  You could always copy your assets into a new project to test, but that's an unfortunate solution.

Comment: Thanks, it was a long night, but built from scratch again and it worked.